# netbeans 6.9.1 very slow

Tags: netbeans

I am editing a php code in netbeans and so far the process is super slow and laggy. It always shows this:
[image]

what should I do to resolve this slowness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- How much RAM do you have? Make sure you have enough free RAM memory. Get a faster processor if applicable.
- What OS are you running on? What do you see in the task bar for Netbeans?
- At times the virus scanning slows down random file access. Make sure they are not scanning your `.php` files. Also, deactivate your Desktop search engine or anything that affects IO.
- Keep an eye on all the Netbeans plugins you have installed. Uninstall unnecessary plugins.
- Think of buying a SSD for performance boost.
- Finally check this article on [Boosting Netbeans Performance](http://phundament.com/en_us/blog?postId=35&postName=boost-your-netbeans-performance)

Comment: 4GB of ram and a 3.3GHZ quad core overclocked processor..windows 7 professional edition not fast enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried notepad++ ?
there is also a light version of NetBeans which only allow to code PHP !
@ http://netbeans.org/downloads/